# bufio.Reader and bufio.Scanner functionality and performance

Tags: go

I had seen several blurbs on the interwebs which had loosely talked about why one should use bufio.Scanner instead of bufio.Reader.

I don't know if my test case is relevant, but I decided to test one vs the other when it comes to reading 1,000,000 lines from a text file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "bufio"
    "time"
    "os"
    //"bytes"
)

func main() {

    fileName := "testfile.txt"

    // Create 1,000,000 integers as strings
    numItems := 1000000
    startInitStringArray := time.Now()

    var input [1000000]string
    //var input []string

    for i:=0; i < numItems; i++ {
        input[i] = strconv.Itoa(i)
        //input = append(input,strconv.Itoa(i))
    }

    elapsedInitStringArray := time.Since(startInitStringArray)
    fmt.Printf("Took %s to populate string array.\n", elapsedInitStringArray)

    // Write to a file
    fo, _ := os.Create(fileName)
    for i:=0; i < numItems; i++ {
        fo.WriteString(input[i] + "\n")
    }

    fo.Close()

    // Use reader
    openedFile, _ := os.Open(fileName)

    startReader := time.Now()
    reader := bufio.NewReader(openedFile)

    for i:=0; i < numItems; i++ {
        reader.ReadLine()
    }
    elapsedReader := time.Since(startReader)
    fmt.Printf("Took %s to read file using reader.\n", elapsedReader)
    openedFile.Close()

    // Use scanner
    openedFile, _ = os.Open(fileName)

    startScanner := time.Now()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(openedFile)

    for i:=0; i < numItems; i++ {
        scanner.Scan()
        scanner.Text()
    }

    elapsedScanner := time.Since(startScanner)
    fmt.Printf("Took %s to read file using scanner.\n", elapsedScanner)
    openedFile.Close()
}
```

A pretty average output I receive on the timings looks like this:

```
Took 44.1165ms to populate string array.
Took 17.0465ms to read file using reader.
Took 23.0613ms to read file using scanner.
```

I am curious, when is it better to use a reader vs. a scanner, and is it based on performance, or functionality?

Comment: They do 2 different things. Do you need the functionality offered by a scanner?

Comment: As I mentioned, I literally started looking at the language just a day or two ago, so I do not fully understand the functionalities of both.

Comment: See [`bufio.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader), [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner), and specifically the [Scanner examples](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_lines), since your usage isn't quite correct.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're getting at. The goal either way is to read a file line by line, and both have superficially similar capabilities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a flawed benchmark. They are not doing the same thing.

```
func (b *Reader) ReadLine() (line []byte, isPrefix bool, err error)
```

returns `[]byte`.

```
func (s *Scanner) Text() string
```

returns `string([]byte)`

To be comparable, use,

```
func (s *Scanner) Bytes() []byte
```

---

It's a flawed benchmark. It reads short strings, the integers from "`0\n`" to "`999999\n`". What real-world data set looks like that?

In the real world we read Shakespeare: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/100:  Plain Text UTF-8: `pg100.txt`.

```
Took 2.973307ms to read file using reader.   size: 5340315 lines: 124787
Took 2.940388ms to read file using scanner.  size: 5340315 lines: 124787
```